# A program with "getchar/putchar" which takes lines of text and prints it each sentence from a new line

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple program using getchar/putchar operators. It must get text in lines and print it out every sentence from the new line.

I wrote this code but it works unexpectedly for me, for example I wrote

```
"I can't program. Help me. Please."
```

it prints out:

```
I can't program.
. Help me.
. Please.
```

Why it's duplicating "."???
My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    int stop=0;
    int i;
    printf("enter your text:  ");
    while((i=getchar())!=EOF){
        if(i=='.')
        {
            stop=1;
            putchar(i);
            putchar('\n');
        }
        if(i==' ')
        {
            if(stop==0) putchar(i);
        }

        else if(i!=' '||i!='.')
        {
            putchar(i);
            stop=0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A but of reformatting would help to **understand the error**

```
if(i == '.') {
    stop = 1;                        // part A
    putchar(i);
    putchar('\n');
}

if(i == ' ') {
    if(stop == 0) {                 // Part B
        putchar(i);
    }
} else if(i != ' ' || i != '.') {
    putchar(i);                     // Part C
    stop = 0;
}
```

When char `i` contains a dot,

- part A is executed (and the dot is printed)
- the test against space fails
- and then the else part is executed

In the else part, the test always succeeds, because you write an "or" instead of an "and".  So the dot is **printed again.** by part C.

**How to fix it :** in your problem there are 3 cases (dot, space, others) and you should avoid to express the same comparaison twice.

A possibility is a series of if/else-if/...

```
if (i == '.') {
     //  process dot
} else if (i == ' ') {
     // process space
} else {
    // process other
}
```

**A better solution** is to use a switch

```
switch (i) {
case '.':
      // process dot
      break;
case ' ':
      // process space
      break;
default:
      // process other
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
else if(i!=' '||i!='.')
```

makes no sense, you meant

```
else if(i != ' ' && i != '.')
```

Comment: ohhh. I knew there was some tiny mistake somewhere in this code!! Thank you a lot!